# How can I reverse the CSS3 transition?

Tags: css, webkit, css-transitions

I have following HTML where hover grows div downwards but I would like to grow upwards.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css"> 

div
{
position:absolute;
top:130px;
left:30px;
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:red;
-webkit-transition:height 2s; 

}

div:hover
{
height:200px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div></div>



</body>
</html>
```

How can I reverse the transition on hover?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try setting the bottom attribute on the div, not top:

```
div
{
position:absolute;
bottom:130px;
left:30px;
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:red;
-webkit-transition:height 2s;     
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/lukemartin/s9jEp/